# Image Fly off Screen using jQuery

Tags: jquery, image, jquery-animate

I'm trying to get an image to fly across the screen once and then stop. I can get it to run in a loop, but it's distracting so i only want it to run once. Anyone know how? (I have to use jQuery)

This is what I have so far,  but I want it to only run once, not in a loop:

```js
var speedX = 20;
var speedY = 1;

setInterval(function() {
  var newLeft = $("img#bee").position().left + speedX + "px";
  var newTop = $("img#bee").position().top + speedY + "px";

  $("img#bee").css({
    left: newLeft,
    top: newTop
  });
  if ($("img#bee").position().left > $(window).width()) {
    $("img#bee").css({
      left: "0px"
    });
  }

  if ($("img#bee").position().left < 0) {
    $("img#bee").css({
      left: $(window).width() + "px"
    });
  }

  if ($("img#bee").position().top > $(window).height()) {
    $("img#bee").css({
      top: $(window).height() + "px"
    });
  }
  $(".stop-btn").click(function() {
    $("img#bee").stop();
  });

}, 20);
```

```css
#bee { display:inline-block; position:absolute }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="bee"  src="https://res-1.cloudinary.com/crunchbase-production/image/upload/c_lpad,h_256,w_256,f_auto,q_auto:eco/v1417678932/jgbmipdnqptqxbig3ywz.jpg" />
```

Comment: Could you please share the code snippet what you are working on? It's much better for helping out you. Thanks!

Comment: edited it, sorry!

Comment: I made you the snippet you should have made from the start

Comment: check the left >= (window.width-img.width)

Answer (score 0):

Removing this `if ($("img#bee").position().left > $(window).width())` condition makes sure that the image position once passed the screen width shouldn't be set back to 0px hence avoid looping.

```js
var speedX = 20;
var speedY = 1;

setInterval(function() {
  var newLeft = $("img#bee").position().left + speedX + "px";
  var newTop = $("img#bee").position().top + speedY + "px";

  $("img#bee").css({
    left: newLeft,
    top: newTop
  });
 

  if ($("img#bee").position().left < 0) {
    $("img#bee").css({
      left: $(window).width() + "px"
    });
  }

  if ($("img#bee").position().top > $(window).height()) {
    $("img#bee").css({
      top: $(window).height() + "px"
    });
  }
  $(".stop-btn").click(function() {
    $("img#bee").stop();
  });

}, 20);
```

```css
#bee { display:inline-block; position:absolute }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="bee"  src="https://res-1.cloudinary.com/crunchbase-production/image/upload/c_lpad,h_256,w_256,f_auto,q_auto:eco/v1417678932/jgbmipdnqptqxbig3ywz.jpg" />
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, You should always explain what you did and why it solves the OP's problem

Comment: Edited my answer to explain what I did and why.

Answer (score 0):

this might not be the best solution but it will work. Just add a transition to it in CSS, and then change the css with javascript/jquery

Javascript:

```
 $(".nameOfElement").click(function() {
    $("#elementID").css({'right' : '0px'});
 });
```

HTML

```
<div id="elementID">Div content</div>
```

CSS

```
#elementID {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  transition: right 1500ms; //time to take to fly accros the screen
}
```